# What is the difference between an API and Command line tool?

Tags: python

In terms of device level integration for infrastructure management including test, status tools.

Example: We can very well use ping command line tool to identify device reachability and have a python script around it or have an API(which I do not understand as of now) called ping check. Wont the API in-turn use ping - command line tool?

Comment: How do you think the `ping` command works? It's just made of code itself.

Comment: No, the API seldom shells out to run a command-line tool or utility. And the difference between them is that an API is an Application Programming Interface (typically a bunch of type declarations and function prototypes for one or more libraries, intended to allow you to use that functionality from your own code), while a command-line tool is a compiled executable file you launch from the command line. :-)

Comment: In the specific case of `ping`, the library solution probably does *not* invoke the `ping` command as a subprocess, but instead sends ICMP echo packets directly.

Answer (score 1):

An API is code invoked via some "calling convention" or "binding" mechanism.  In other words, it is code which has its own (perhaps semi-standardized) way of being invoked.  Examples are the C calling convention (which varies per OS), .NET, Python, REST, etc.

A command line tool is invoked by "exec"ing some binary code which follows the operating system's convention (e.g. MachO, ELF, PE).  To "exec" the tool is to load its binary code from a file into memory, and set the instruction pointer to a known location.

Typically, an API produces results of various types via a "return" mechanism, and these types can be strings, arrays, etc.  A command line tool typically produces results by writing to a file, and also emits a numeric return code to indicate success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

API is acronym for application programming interface. While command line tool is anything that is invoked from command line.

The first is about programming, functions, arguments and return values. Is a contract between the program writer and program caller.

The second is about a program that uses text as its user interface.

The first is about a programming contract, an specification, a pattern. It's an interface.

The second is a program it self.

If you take `ls` command as example. The /bin/ls binary is a command line tool. The C `readdir` function used by `ls` obeys or has API.